# PowerShell ISE as C editor (like gEdit with embedded terminal)?

Tags: powershell, ide, syntax-highlighting, gedit

I've just discovered PowerShell in Windows 7 and realised that it comes with an ISE too.

In Linux, I use gEdit with an embedded terminal when writing C programs and I've been looking for an alternative in Windows. PowerShell ISE seems perfect except for the fact it doesn't highlight syntax for anything other than PowerShell Scripts.

Is there a way around this? Or is there a **decent** text editor (like Notepad++) for Windows that lets me embed an instance of cmd.exe or PowerShell into it?

Comment: There is a windows version of gedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I missed this, but Notepad++ has a plugin called "NppExec" which gives you an embedded Command Prompt.

To get it go to **Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager** and find "NppExec"

If, like me, you find the extra text it outputs annoying, turn it off by going to:
**Plugins -> NppExec** and Check **No internal messages**.

Answer (score 0):

I know people who use Visual Studios and the PowerGUI Extension to write their Powershell scripts.  Probably a bit overkill.

The only other IDE that is widely used for Powershell is the standalone PowerGUI.